# function in R that can test all cells in any different columns and return a new column, with a spacific conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I need a function in R that can test all cells in any different columns and return a new column, with the following condition:

- If at least one column has 1 return 1
- If all columns have 0 return 0
- If all columns have NA return NA
- If one column has 0 and the rest has NA return 0
- If one column has NA and the rest has 0 return 0

Here is an example:
I have two columns A and B

```
A = c(1,1,1,  0,0,0,  NA)  
B = c(1,0,NA, 1,0,NA, NA)
```

And I need a function that returns the following column:

```
Z = c(1,1,1,   1,0,0,  NA)
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can use `rowSums` i.e. `v1 <- as.integer(rowSums(dat!=0, na.rm=TRUE)>0); v1*NA^!rowSums(!is.na(dat))`

Comment: I found a perfect answer to my question, and i want to share it with you:  

A = c(1,1,1, 0,0,0, NA)
B = c(1,0,NA, 1,0,NA, NA)
Z=rep(2,length(A))
for (i in 1:length(A)){
  ceiling(mean(c(A[i],B[i]),na.rm=T))->Z[i]
}
Z[is.na(Z<0)]<-NA
Z

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the use of `pmax` with the na.rm parameter set will deliver the desired results:

```
> pmax(A,B, na.rm=TRUE)
[1]  1  1  1  1  0  0 NA
```

I cannot tell if it will handle all the edge case that might arise in situations with greater numbers of "columns" (which are really vectors in your example. I'm assuming that all "columns" are numeric.

Comment: Thanks
but unfortunately, it doesn't work with multi columns!

Comment: You should always post a problem that illustrates the full complexity.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums`

```
v1 <- as.integer(rowSums(dat!=0, na.rm=TRUE)>0);
v1*NA^!rowSums(!is.na(dat))
#[1]  1  1  1  1  0  0 NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>%
    mutate(Z = coalesce(A, B))
```